# calculatematrix using the javascript API rather than REST

Tags: mootools, here-api

I'm trying to use the calculatematrix API to take a load of destinations and calculate the driving distance to them from a given location (my examples first convert the postcode to a latlng)

Using the REST api and JQuery I can get this to work fine. See this JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vostrx9m/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
  data: {
    app_id: 'XHHvADl4hLUQWLbUOGNp',
    app_code: '-Zhl4CYrM03JxXabdROElA',
    searchtext: 'TR9 6QA'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var LatLon = data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition[0].Latitude + "," + data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition[0].Longitude;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
      data: {
        mode: 'fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;',
        start0: LatLon,
        destination0: '50.395118,-4.934356',
        destination1: '50.464852,-5.031908',
        destination2: '50.541548,-4.938789',
        app_id: 'XHHvADl4hLUQWLbUOGNp',
        app_code: '-Zhl4CYrM03JxXabdROElA',
        summaryAttributes: 'distance,traveltime'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        for (i in data.response.matrixEntry) {
          $('p').append("dest(" + i + "), " + data.response.matrixEntry[i].summary.distance + " meters, " + data.response.matrixEntry[i].summary.travelTime + " seconds<br\>");
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

However our site uses MooTools, so I've rewritten this against mootools and I now get CORS issues. "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status." It looks like the preflight gets a permission error - see this JSFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/1av2wkye/5/

```
getDistancesFromPostCode('TR84LP')
function getDistancesFromPostCode(StartPostCode) {
    console.log('getDistancesFromPostCode: ' + StartPostCode)
    var req = new Request({
        method: 'get', 
        url: "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json", 
        data: {
            app_id: 'XHHvADl4hLUQWLbUOGNp',
        app_code: '-Zhl4CYrM03JxXabdROElA',
            searchtext: StartPostCode
        }, 
        onComplete: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            var StartLatLon = data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition[0].Latitude + "," + data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition[0].Longitude;
            console.log(StartLatLon)
            getDistancesFromLatLng(StartLatLon)
        },
    }).send();
}

function getDistancesFromLatLng(StartLatLon) {
    console.log('getDistancesFromLatLng: ' + StartLatLon)
    var req = new Request({
        method: 'get', 
        url: "https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json", 
        data: {
            mode: 'fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;',
            start0: StartLatLon,
            destination0: '50.4153650,-5.0698703',destination1: '50.4154830,-5.0698890',destination2: '50.473036820553446, -4.707902895605457',
            app_id: 'XHHvADl4hLUQWLbUOGNp',
        app_code: '-Zhl4CYrM03JxXabdROElA',
            summaryAttributes: 'distance,traveltime'
        }, 
        onComplete: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            for (i in data.response.matrixEntry) {
                console.log("dest(" + i + "), " + data.response.matrixEntry[i].summary.distance + " meters, " + data.response.matrixEntry[i].summary.travelTime + " seconds<br\>");
            }
        },
    }).send();
}
```

Any ideas what MooTools is doing wrong or how I fix that?

If not, I tried a different tactic by writing things against the Javascript API and I got the geoencode working, but I cannot see any reference to the calculatematric API in the JavaScript documentation, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the request should be a JSONP type request , i would guess using Request.JSONP from MooTools should help with the CORS issue. HERE Javascript API does not have support for the calculate matrix end point of the API.